# Clean architecture: use case mixing

Tags: clean-architecture

I'm trying to understand how clean architecture works, last project i had a user, he can add a payment card and buy a subscription (example use case), but when it's new user, add and buy integrated as one step

[Use case sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q77RU.png)

According to what has been read, it should have two "Interactors", one "AddPayment" and "Purchase", , but... how can I mix:
The user can do both separately, but when he is new, in registration process he adds the payment method and makes the charge in one step,

I think I should have an "Add and pay" use case, but it would have repeated code and a broken paradigm, I see these options:

1. Make a third use case with repeated code
2. Merge from controller
3. Make a use case that calls the other two

How have you solved it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually make a **base use case** that calls the other two. For this base use case I define a new request model that contains the request models of the others . The same applies for the response model. But sometime the request or response models have something in common and I create more condensed models.

I think that a base use case fits best to the [include relationship](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-soft-arch/9.7.0?topic=diagrams-include-relationships) of the use case uml model.

```
            +-----------+
            | AddAndPay |  
            +-----------+
             |         |
             V         V
         +-----+    +-----+
         | Add |    | Pay | 
         +-----+    +-----+
```

The `AddAndPay` use case also handles failures of one of the use cases. E.g. if  pay fails you might not want to add a payment card. Maybe you must invoke a `RemovePaymentCard` use case then or your transaction boundary is the `AddAndPay` use case.